# Keyboard hides Textarea inside a Hybrd Webview in Xamarin forms

Tags: android, webview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In xamarin forms I am making use of hybrid webview to display texarea and entry fields.When I try to enter some data inside the textarea the keyboard pops up and hides the textarea.
Thus I am not able to see the text that i'm typing.It does not auto scroll to the current cursor position.I have read that adding
           `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` 
to the android manifest file does the trick.
But is it possible to apply the above property to only the webview(without applying for other views)?Or is there any other way to auto scroll the view so that entry field(cursor)is just above the keyboard.
Please help

Comment: Put your hybrd webview in scroll view.

Comment: i tried but it didnt work.Is there any other way? @ZiyadGodil

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 11):

In `App.xaml.cs` you can add:

```
using AndroidSpecific = Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;

public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AndroidSpecific.Application.SetWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(this, AndroidSpecific.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
    …
```

Which I guess is less idiomatic than Artūras Paleičikas' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46359782/132599) but achieves the same affect.

Comment: I did this but can't

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
...

 global::Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>()
                .UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
```

Answer (score 1):

Reviewing the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/platform-specifics/consuming/android#setting-the-soft-keyboard-input-mode

I think it's better to use:

```
<Application ...
    xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
    android:Application.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust="Resize">
    ...
</Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your webview inside of a scroll view and handle the focused function , this help me in xamarin forms ios application.

```
  private void Handle_Focused(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.FocusEventArgs e)
  {
      SCr_View.ScrollToAsync(0, Web_View.Y * 50, false); // 50 is height u want to move up
  }
```

Try this up.

Comment: idea is when your text area is clicked or focused , we need to externally move or change the height of your textarea for that you can use scrollview  for better GUI.