# page not scrolled when clicked input and display keyboard in webview xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I try to develop android apps using Xamarin Forms.
There is an input in a webview.When clicked the input , keyboard is displayed.But i can not see what i write.Input is not scrolled up.

XAML and WebViewRenderer contents as below.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:deneme"
         ">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>.RowDefinitions>
            <local:HybridWebView x:Name="webView" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            </local:HybridWebView>
            <Button Text="Button1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <Button Text="Button2"/>
            <Label Text="Hidden"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

```
public class HybridWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<HybridWebView, Android.Webkit.WebView>
{

    Context _context;

    public HybridWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            var webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(_context);
            webView.ScrollBarFadeDuration = 0;
            webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            webView.SetWebViewClient(new JavascriptWebViewClient($"javascript: {JavascriptFunction}"));
            SetNativeControl(webView);
        }
    }
}
```

In order to set html input position prior keyboard,what should i do ?

Comment: Hi, Did you solved it? Do you have a solution for ios?

Comment: `ScrollView` and web view together isn't the best idea I think ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Soft Keyboard Input Mode on Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/soft-keyboard-input-mode) described in the document.

In xaml:

```
<Application ...
             xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             android:Application.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust="Resize">
  ...
</Application>
```

Or in code behind:

```
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;
...

App.Current.On<Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
```

Refer: [keyboard-hides-textarea-inside-a-hybrd-webview-in-xamarin-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46356840/keyboard-hides-textarea-inside-a-hybrd-webview-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: I added Window.SetSoftInputMode(Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustResize); in MainActivty class same as you offred.I can scroll page manually when keayboard displayed.But i want to automatic page scroll up when keyboard displayed.

Comment: @Mehmet Can you share me the url you are using?

Comment: It works for me. Thank you @nevermore for this quick solution.
https://prnt.sc/li2R7sJ-DfWr

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility) in the Android docs and especially the `android:windowSoftInputMode` ([docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)) attribute of activity.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line to your code

```
Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustPan);
```

Comment: Did you try to rebuild? Perhaps try this in the Renderer var window = ((Activity)Forms.Context).Window;
window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustPan);